# IOS 6 device orientation and pixels issue

Tags: iphone, ios6, orientation

I have a tabbarController based application. I wrote the code for orientation and it works fine. But because of these, I face an issue of 20 pixels in the app, i.e the navigationBar shifts 20 pixels down.

If I remove the following piece of code from the didFinishLaunching, the 20 pixels issue gets resolved but orientation does not work.

```
[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

Comment: Can you add more details about the project type? I mean, if the app is targeted for iOS5, but you compile it for iOS6, rotation problems can appear. You can even look in the project file, and check which orientations are available. Add these information to your question.

Comment: The app is targeted for iOS6 and I ma compiling it also for ios 6.

Answer (score 0):

I get this EXACT same problem with my app... and **at first** I had no workaround solution other than to literally leave 20 pixels of space ahead of my UI that I would want to begin with and it would just snap in place.

But just yesterday I came across this solution, use this code and it **should** work like it did for me:

```
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
```

Comment: hi Rohan, So do I have to make this change to all the subviews?

Comment: I tried it with one of the view controllers, does not help :(